# Jekyll: Using values from _config.yml in SCSS

Tags: sass, jekyll, liquid

In my Jekyll project, I have the following in my `_config.yml` file:

```
colors:
  - name: red
    hex: '#FF0000'
  - name: yellow
    hex: '#FFFF00'
  - name: blue
    hex: '#0000FF'
```

In `assets/css/colors.scss`, I want to create classes for the colors as follows:

```
{% for color in site.colors %}
.{{ color.name }} {
  color: {{ color.hex }};
}
{% endfor %}
```

When I do so, I get the following error:

```
Error in _assets/css/background-test.scss:6 Invalid CSS after "}": expected selector or at-rule, was "{% for color in..." 
  Liquid Exception: Invalid CSS after "}": expected selector or at-rule, was "{% for color in..." in _includes/head.html, included in _layouts/default.html
jekyll 3.0.1 | Error:  Invalid CSS after "}": expected selector or at-rule, was "{% for color in..."
```

Is there a way to get Liquid to process the values from the `_config.yml` file in the SCSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want Jekyll to process your scss file you must add a front matter to it.

This works :

```
---
# empty front matter
---
@charset "utf-8";

{% for color in site.colors %}
.{{ color.name }} {
  color: {{ color.hex }};
}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks, that does the trick. The Liquid tags don't work seem to work within SCSS partials, but that's a basic limitation to work around.

Comment: So, maybe you can approve this answer.

Comment: just a side node, if your scss files are @import each other, only the main Sass file needs front matter, for me further front matters caused syntax errors