# Jekyll: Using values from _config.yml in SCSS partial

Tags: sass, jekyll, liquid

In my Jekyll project, I have the following in my `_config.yml` file:

```
colors:
  - name: red
    hex: '#FF0000'
  - name: yellow
    hex: '#FFFF00'
  - name: blue
    hex: '#0000FF'
```

In `assets/css/colors.scss`, I want to create classes for the colors as follows:

```
{% for color in site.colors %}
.{{ color.name }} {
  color: {{ color.hex }};
}
{% endfor %}
```

I want to `@import` the `colors.scss` file into `main.scss`, but I when I do so, I get the following error:

```
Error in _assets/css/background-test.scss:6 Invalid CSS after "}": expected selector or at-rule, was "{% for color in..." 
  Liquid Exception: Invalid CSS after "}": expected selector or at-rule, was "{% for color in..." in _includes/head.html, included in _layouts/default.html
jekyll 3.0.1 | Error:  Invalid CSS after "}": expected selector or at-rule, was "{% for color in..."
```

Is there a way to get Liquid to process the values from the `_config.yml` file in the SCSS partial?

Comment: I think this question is a duplicate of your previous one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34274368/jekyll-using-values-from-config-yml-in-scss

Comment: My previous question didn't specify a SCSS partial. Your answer to the other question was correct, but I'm unable to get this to work inside the SCSS partial.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Only your main.scss will be parsed by Jekyll.

Once parsed with Liquid it is passed to sass/scss processor. So, any @imported file will not be parsed by Liquid.

Comment: Got it, thanks — that makes much more sense now. It seems that the only way to make this work is to break out any SCSS generated by Liquid into a separate file that can contain front matter.